# VBA ADODB test is two fields are convertable?

Tags: vba, ms-access, oracle11g, ado, adodb

I'm writing a function that copies contents of a `recordset`(from `ADODB` library) into another. Specifically copying some contents of `Oracle g11`(fragment of it) to `Access 2007`.

Becasue I want to make sure that I write either all contents or none at all- I am checking if the `Fields` of each `recordset` are the same(have same `Name` and `Type`).

Problem is that very quickly I stumbled upon a case were one recordset has field Type `adVarChar` and the other has `adVarWChar`. To be honest I am not sure how are these data types different but as I understand they both represent a variable lenght character field, and correct me if I'm wrong but I should be able to write contents of `adVarChar` into `adVarWChar`.

Now I undrstand that there are many more types of strings that `ADODB` recognizes, and that there many types of integers, doubles, floats ....  you get the point.

So my question is how can I detect if you can write/coerce/convert contents of one data type(`ADODB`'s data types) to another?

Is there a susinct and **DRY** way of doing this?

See my code for reference

```
Sub AppendRecords(NewRecords As ADODB.Recordset, OriginalRecords As ADODB.Recordset)
    Dim AllFieldsMatch As Boolean
    Dim Iterator       As Integer
    Dim ActiveField    As Field
    Dim FieldCount     As Integer
    Dim FieldNames()   As String
    Dim FieldValues()  As Variant

    FieldCount = NewRecords.Fields.Count

    For Iterator = 0 To FieldCount - 1
        If NewRecords.Fields(Iterator).Name <> OriginalRecords.Fields(Iterator).Name Then
            AllFieldsMatch = False
            Err.Raise 10001, "AppendRecords", "Field names are not matching."
        End If
    Next

    For Iterator = 0 To FieldCount
        If NewRecords.Fields(Iterator).Type <> OriginalRecords.Fields(Iterator).Type Then
            AllFieldsMatch = False
            Err.Raise 10002, "AppendRecords", "Field Types are not matching."
        End If
    Next
    If NewRecords.EOF And NewRecords.BOF Then
        Err.Raise 10003, "AppendRecords", "There are no records in new Recordset."
    End If

    Iterator = 0
    ReDim FieldNames(Iterator To FieldCount - 1)
    ReDim FieldValues(Iterator To FieldCount - 1)

    For Each ActiveField In NewRecords.Fields
        FieldNames(Iterator) = ActiveField.Name
    Next

    While Not NewRecords.EOF
        For Each ActiveField In NewRecords.Fields
            FieldNames(Iterator) = ActiveField.Value
        Next

        OriginalRecords.AddNew FieldNames, FieldValues

        NewRecords.MoveNext
        'LogCompletedJob "GetCoverageTable"  'Ignore for now
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before to map ADO field data types with DAO field data types. However I haven't done this with Oracle. This link may help:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14232/apb.htm

Or this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-data-type-mappings

You could try and update the field value without checking data types. Add error handling to catch obvious fails and then compare the contents of the two field values to see if the data made it across.

i.e. Remove this:

```
For Iterator = 0 To FieldCount
    If NewRecords.Fields(Iterator).Type <> OriginalRecords.Fields(Iterator).Type Then
        AllFieldsMatch = False
        Err.Raise 10002, "AppendRecords", "Field Types are not matching."
    End If
Next
```

And add error handling/checks to this part of the code:

```
For Each ActiveField In NewRecords.Fields
    FieldNames(Iterator) = ActiveField.Value
Next
```